# Group id in insertMany operation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to attach to all my documents (which will be added to my mongoDB by `insertMany`) a groupId. The group Id should be incremented from one set of documents to another. Is there a way to do that with mongoDB?

F.ex. this is my query

```
try {
   db.products.insertMany( [
      { item: "card", qty: 15 }, // add groupId: 1
      { item: "envelope", qty: 20 }, // add groupId: 1
      { item: "stamps" , qty: 30 } // add groupId: 1
   ] );
} catch (e) {
   print (e);
}
```

Next query should get `groupId: 2` in all documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these writes are independent you might need to read current `groupId` from DB & increment it for the following operation.

```
let currentIdObj = db.products.find({}, {projection:{_id:0, groupId:1}}).sort({groupId:-1}).limit(1)
```

Or it would be easy if you could store this current `groupId` some where as a configuration setup - Can either be in a different collection, that way it would be easy to query & get results faster (Can just maintain one single doc at any given time with latest value or a single doc for each unique Id with time it was created just for reference). Also have an index on that field.

Comment: You can also take advantage of sorting on `_id` & thereby  getting last one - as latest document will be the first when sorted in descending order(As `groupId`'s are incremental it will work). But this might fail when you've two parallel calls where one writes 2 & other writes 1, if inserting of all docs where 2 finishes first than those with `groupId :1`..